# Deploy contract without verifying it with ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js

I can already deploy verified contracts using https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/.

But they are always already verified after being deployed. I tried replacing the interface parameter (abi) by an empty array but it's still able to verify the contract.

Is there a way to deploy unverified contracts ?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean with 'verified'? That's a term usually used with external services such as Etherscan where you submit the source code for verification. And that kind of stuff is not needed for deployment

Comment: Yes i meant verified by etherscan or bscscan. My contract is by default verified when i publish it but i would need it to be unverified...

Comment: Contracts do not get verified by default. You need a plugin for it and an Etherscan account. Please go through your deployment process and see if it automatically verifies the contracts.

Comment: Ok i understood what happened if a contract with the same bytecode is already deployed it is automatically verified. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, sure, didn't think of that.